# Python Programming: Need to add spaces between character in a split string

Tags: python

I have to print out every third letter of a text with spaces between and none at the end. I can do everything but the spaces between each of the letters.

Here is what I have.

```
line = input('Message? ')                                          
print(line[0]+line[3::3].strip())
```

Answer (score 7):

To join things with spaces, use `join()`.  Consider the following:

```
>>> line = '0123456789'
>>> ' '.join(line[::3])
'0 3 6 9'
```

Answer (score -2):

Since you're using Python 3, you can use `*` to unpack the line and send each element as an argument to `print()`, which uses a space as the default separator between arguments. You don't need to separate `line[0]` from the rest - you can include it in the slice (`[0::3]`), or it'll be used by default (`[::3]`). Also, there's no need to use `strip()`, as the newline character that you send with <kbd>Enter</kbd> is not included in the string when you use `input()`.

```
print(*input('Message? ')[::3])
```

Comment: Thnx, i think i was looking for something that would be more complex and in doing so forgot to think about any simpler options

Comment: This will print the required output very tidily, providing a good example of Python 3's `print()` function with a clear explanation. Why the downvote?

Comment: How to use the separated arguments ?

Comment: @zetysz - They already are used. They are unpacked and sent to `print()`, which prints them with a space separator as the question specifies.

Comment: I want a list  as a result if possible .`[1, 2, 3]`

Comment: @zetysz - That's not in the scope of the question and this answer, but `mylist = list(input('Message? ')[::3])`.

Comment: Why is this getting so many downvotes? What is actually wrong with it?